# Query Windows Version

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I am putting together a table with server names and their properties such as Number of CPUs, Cores, memory, OS version, etc. I am trying to find an easy way to get the windows OS version number in SSMS. Does anyone know of a query that I can use to return the Windows OS version in SSMS.

Answer (score 5):

This information should be available in the [`sys.dm_os_windows_info`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204565.aspx) table:

```
SELECT windows_release
FROM   sys.dm_os_windows_info;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `@@VERSION` global variable like below which should give you SQL Server version along with underlying OS version

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

You will get a result like

*...... on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)*

Comment: I need windows version not SQL Server version.

Comment: @WesPalmer, that gives both actually.

Comment: Hence *along with underlying OS version*